# replace a url (or a string containing multiple urls) with a value returned from a function

Tags: r, url, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

we have a `df` like so:

```r
df <- data.frame(id= c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 urls= c(NA,NA,"https://www.bing.com",
                         "https://www.bing.com https://www.google.com",
                         "https://github.com/"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then we have a function that read in real urls, and get the `title` tag of each page. Like so-

```r
get_title_tag <- function(url) {

  if (is.na(ifelse(url == "", NA, url))) {
    return(NA)
  }
  else if(identical(xml2::read_html(url), character(0))){
    return(NA)
  }
  else{
    page <- xml2::read_html(url)

    path_to_title <- "/html/head/title"

    conf_nodes <- rvest::html_nodes(page, xpath = path_to_title)

    title <- rvest::html_text(conf_nodes)

    #return(title)
   return ("PAGE_TITLE")
  }
}
```

**The problem is that the element at 4th position at `urls` column contains two consecutive urls, so we get errors**. We have looked at several posts here in the forums however none have problems like what We are facing.

Our goal is to get this output:

```r
> df
  id                                          urls
1  1                                          <NA>
2  2                                          <NA>
3  3                                         PAGE_TITLE
4  4                              PAGE_TITLE PAGE_TITLE
5  5                                         PAGE_TITLE
```

I have tried this method that separates the urls, but expands the df which is not what I want:

```r
urls_only_vector <- df %>%
                      mutate(urls= strsplit(as.character(urls), " ")) %>%
                      unnest(urls) #%>% select("urls")
```

**Using this method I can read urls one at a time, but again, since it expands my dataframe, I was wondering if there is something else I can do?** Can I get an hint please? I will cherish any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to get `url`'s in different rows, apply `get_title_tag` function get the title and combine the data again grouping by id so that size of data remains the same.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(urls, sep = '\\s+') %>%
  mutate(title = purrr::map_chr(urls, get_title_tag)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(title = toString(title))
```

Comment: Ronak were you my grandfather in past life? You always show me a path lol. Man why did I not thought of that `group_by(id)`. Excellent thinking! Thanks a million sir :)